# A strang math calculation

Tags: javascript

Consider the following calculation

```
3 * 20.9
```

normally it equals to `62.7`. However, when I calculate it in javascript, the output is `62.699999999999996`. And what's more I found that `7`, `11` will also produce the wrong answer. Why it goes wrong and how to make it right? I think it's about the binary?

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u6pxbzse/1/)

Comment: It's because of the floating point precision. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: Duplicate question: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: The imprecision occurs because 0.9 can't be mapped to a finite binary floating point number. You can use libraries such as BigDecimal if this poses a problem for you: https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep only 1 decimal. Use

```
(3*20.9).toFixed(1)
```

Updated ***[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6pxbzse/2/)***

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Number((3*20.9).toFixed(1));
```